# How to debug revel app in goland?

Tags: debugging, go, revel, goland

I would like to debug my revel application with Jetbrain's gogland built in debugger but gogland run configuration allowing to setup either package or file run scenario not debug process started by `revel run myapp`.

Comment: Debugging processes is not implemented yet (Gogland EAP 7). Here is related issue that you can follow to get updates on this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-620

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Gogland is [Goland](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/)

I find official [manual](https://revel.github.io/manual/debug.html) for create debug-config. I'll post here if you do not mind...

**INTELLIJ DEBUGGING (GOLAND)**

1. Create your project, for this example i will be using canonical “revel new github.com/myaccount/my-app”
2. “revel run github.com/myaccount/my-app” to generate tmp/main.go - this file is needed by intellij
3. Shutdown the running server
4. Create run configuration and in “Program arguments” add “-importPath github.com\myaccount\my-app -srcPath \src -runMode dev"
5. Point “File” to \src\github.com\myaccount\my-app\app\tmp\main.go
6. In “before launch” add “Run external tool”. There: Program: \bin\revel(.exe) Paramerets: build github.com/myaccount/my-app

*It works for Linux&Windows*

Comment: The revel build command requires two arguments, the app itself (which you have), and the target path which will be overwritten. The instructions above fail due to the missing target path.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Gogland built-in debugger is [delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve).

I think you must try run debug with option `attach`:

```
Attach to an already running process and begin debugging it.

This command will cause Delve to take control of an already running process, and
begin a new debug session.  When exiting the debug session you will have the
option to let the process continue or kill it.

Usage:
  dlv attach pid [flags]
```

I don't have installed gogland now, but I had similar problem in past.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to install delve separatly. I would rather use gogland's bundled binary of delve and use GUI debugger which is in gogland.

Comment: In fact, I've installed gogland. I've found `dlv` in bin. But I did not found a possibility to customize start of `dlv`. 
Than I look here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/GO?q=dlv%20attach

I don't see a possibility to configure attach to pid from gogland.